# Avoid usage of non-permanent URLs to reference papers

Tags: discussion

Various posts or or.stackexchange contain urls to reference papers, e.g.:[Usages of logarithmic mean in optimization](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/298/usages-of-logarithmic-mean-in-optimization)

Problem is that these URLs can change, and without a reference to the author/title/year of the paper it is virtually impossible to trace back the paper that was referred to in the first place.

Is there a way that we can stimulate the author's to include a proper reference? Is there some way to moderate this?

Comment: This is a very good point. I am guilty of this myself. I'm not sure what the solution is -- hopefully folks will have some ideas.

Comment: The issue you're describing is called [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Answer (score 5):

Agree! I like the style of how the reference is given in this answer:
https://or.stackexchange.com/a/800/

An alternative would be to require links be to doi's.

I'd support having persistent references (however we decide) be a community norm. E.g., to get started maybe edit some answers to reflect this and then move to asking folks who haven't followed the style to edit their answers.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. It is definitely helpful when someone posts a full reference like in the post you linked to. It's also kind of a pain. So linking to a doi would be a reasonable (and easier) alternative.

Comment: I also like the idea of any of us taking the initiative to edit some posts, and hopefully we'll all get into the habit of providing more solid references.

Comment: I agree easier is better

Comment: I like that referencing style too. I just don't know how that's done. And since I haven't earned the right to edit posts yet I can't check how it's done myself.

Comment: @JorisKinable it’s not done any special way. You just use markdown to add italics, etc where needed.