# Do we have a reference for reference requests?

Tags: discussion, questions

**Context:** There are now <strike>43</strike> 111 questions tagged [reference-request](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request).

The current [tag wiki](https://or.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/info) guidance is

> For questions asking for references from the literature or textbooks on specific topics. If possible, references should be accompanied by a hyperlink to the article for accessibility.

Related OR Meta discussions like [Avoid usage of non-permanent URLs to reference papers](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/192/491) are very limited in scope.

Our own Help Center even states to

> avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid.

Also from OR Meta,

> *Stack Exchange was not intended to be a list of links or a search engine telling users where to find their answers elsewhere*. — Robert Cartaino ♦ ([source](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/a/198/491))

**Peer Sites:**
[CrossValidated (stats)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) has a [related discussion](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1593/177387) on this issue including guidelines on [using community wiki](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1595/177387) for certain reference requests. They refer to these guidelines [officially](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/references/info).

[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) has [language](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2498/572874) to avoid "big lists" ([source](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/info)).

[Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) seems to have address this this topic by creating the [specific-reference](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-reference) tag which has [usage guidance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-reference/info) that separates these "*What is the canonical source for X*?" or "*What is the first paper on Y*?" from general topical questions to use the [resource-recommendation](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendation) tag. The two tags are considered mutually exclusive. These topical [resource recommendation tags](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/resource-recommendations/info) must comply with the [usage policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4697).

> Resource recommendations must ask for descriptive answers. It's not
> enough to ask for a list of books that cover topic X — a simple Amazon
> search can provide that.
>
> Instead, you should ask for recommendations, which specify:
>
> - What the book covers
> - How it covers it — is it rigorous? Intuitive? How is the writer's style?
> - What are the prerequisites?
>
> and similar questions. (Source: [Physics.SE FAQ](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4698))

**Discussion:**

I expect these kinds of questions will likely continue on the site and we should note these questions can be [highly useful](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/57/491).

Here are some examples of reference requests in reverse chronological order:<sup>[1]</sup>

- [Any good resource for solving power system optimization in GAMS?](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/6179/491)
- [Books in applied Online Optimization](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/4491/491)
- [Categorization of optimization models](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/3069/491)
- [Reference request for Evacuation Planning](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/3025/491) <sup>[2]</sup>
- [Good textbook for queueing theory and performance modeling](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/1275/491) <sup>[2]</sup>
- [Bridge the gap between theory and practice in Integer Programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/1292/491)
- [PhD-level textbooks on linear programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/2741/491)
- [Looking for books in the same style as Hans Kellerer 2004, Knapsack Problems](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/2932/491)
- [references on the empirical study on the practice of OR](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/986/491)
- [References for "metric" network flow problems](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/946/491)
- [Good sources on developing mathematical models](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/905/491) **(closed)**
- [Classics in Operations Research from around WW II?](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/375/491) <sup>[2]</sup>
- [Recommended books/materials for practical applications of Operations Research in industry](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/117/491)
- [Single reference for Mixed Integer Programming formulations to linearize, handle logical constraints and disjunctive constraints, do Big M, etc?](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/57/491) <sup>[2], also a fav of mine</sup>

Some questions are of dubious quality but without the tag:

- [What are good reference books for introduction to operations research?](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/869/491) **(closed)**

The amount of research or even detail provided by the asker varies greatly from [question](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/3025/491) to [question](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/946/491).

The lack of guidance on [reference-request](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) questions currently leaves the site open to low quality generic questions that may have limited value for future visitors (similar to the *gimme the codez* questions on StackOverflow). While some users already [attempt to improve these questions before answering](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/3025/reference-request-for-evacuation-planning#comment3352_3025), many (including myself) have rushed in to provide answers (see [2]). Perhaps the community should consider how these questions should be asked and how we should curate them on the site.

**A few questions for discussion:**

1. What research is expected of someone asking a
   [reference-request](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) question?
2. What should be included in the question?
3. How should the community moderate these questions? (and if needed, improve their quality to help askers)

---

<sub>[1] Examples only include literature-specific requests (books, papers, references) and do not include benchmark problems, courses, etc.</sub> 
<sub>[2] Disclosure for questions that I have also answered.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, the things we expect of someone asking a [reference-request](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) question are pretty similar to the things we ask of someone asking any other question: do research, show your work, be specific, make it relevant to others, etc.

I agree that some of the questions you link to do a better job than others of ticking those boxes, but that's true of non-reference-request questions too.

By the way, I fully agree that these questions are welcome on OR.SE, even if other SE sites frown on them.

What do others think?

Comment: FWIW Math.SE, Stats.SE and MathOverflow (MO), among more similar sites, have [reference-request] as a tag with a similar tag description. I suppose the rules, especially in MO, apply well here.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Good find.  I should have looked at other sites with similar content.  Will look over those and edit into question. For example, CrossValidated (stats) has [this guidance](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1595/177387) linked in their tag.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire MO has no [guidance](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/reference-request/info) on the tag usage.  I've updated the question to include CrossValidated (CV) and Mathematics.